# How can I reach iterator's value in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

Here is my code:

```
    map<string,pair<string,string> >::iterator last;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,vector<int> > >::iterator location;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,vector<int> > >::iterator location1;

auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);

    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() || location != getMatchMap().end())
    {
        location1 = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
        if(location1 != getMatchMap().end())
            getCourseScList().insert({s,{make_pair(location1->first.first,location1->second.first)}});
```

What I am doing here is when my predicate function works,I will insert these data to another map. 
However when I try to print this with this code:

```
for(last = getCourseScList().begin();last!=getCourseScList().end();++last)
        {
            cout<<last->first<<"\t\t\t\t"<<(last->second.first)<<"\t\t\t"<<last->second.second<<endl;
        }
```

I cant see any value. How can i insert the iterator's data to another map?

Whole code is here:

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule()
{
    string c,s;
    int courseNum;
    int i = 0;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map<string,pair<string,string> >::iterator last;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,vector<int> > >::iterator location;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,vector<int> > >::iterator location1;

    dummy1:
    cout<<"Enter the student name"<<endl;
    cin >> s;
    cout<<"Enter the course names you want"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);

    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() || location != getMatchMap().end())
    {
        location1 = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
        if(location1 != getMatchMap().end())
            getCourseScList().insert({s,{make_pair(location1->first.first,location1->second.first)}});
}
    else
    {
        cout<<"The course or student you wrote isn't available.Please enter existed courses!"<<endl;
        goto dummy1;
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    char dummy;
    cout<<"\nDo tou want to create a new schedule?Press y or n."<<endl;
    cin>>dummy;
    if(dummy == 'Y' || dummy == 'y')
        goto dummy1;
    else
    {
        for(last = getCourseScList().begin();last!=getCourseScList().end();++last)
        {
            cout<<last->first<<"\t\t\t\t"<<(last->second.first)<<"\t\t\t"<<last->second.second<<endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `iter->second` is the value from the map...

Comment: Yes, I know that. However when I insert this iter->second to another map. I cant see any value in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "see any value"?  If you insert a copy of the value in the other map, it will be in the other map.  Without actual (complete, compilable) code that illustrates what you are trying to do, noone can give you any better help than that.

Comment: With for loop, I have to see the map's values,right? However compiler doesnt print anything to the screen. I will add the whole code too.

Comment: at a guess `getCourseScList()` returns the map by value so you have undefined behaviour. Please post a [mre]

Comment: `map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,vector<int> > >&Course::getMatchMap()
{
    return matchMap;
}`

Comment: You still haven't included the code -- see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)